# Gradle Multi Project with Java 9 and Java 8

Tags: gradle, java-8, java-9, multi-project

I would like to migrate a gradle multi project to java 9. Instead of trying a big bang I would like to go step by step. My idea is to start from top (main module) and then work my way down. This implies, that I will have a main module in Java 9 while others are still in Java 8.
If my info is correct a good approach is to have the modules in java 8 integrated as automatic modules. It works fine with 3rd party libs as jar's, but I do not know how to teach gradle to do it with my own java 8 modules.
Imagine I got a Main Java 9 Module 'java9' and a Java 8 Library Module 'java8'
What I did so far:
'java8' build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

ext.moduleName = 'java8module.main'

jar {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    manifest {
        attributes('Automatic-Module-Name': moduleName)
    }
}
```

This gives me a java8 jar with a Module Name I decided for in the MANIFEST.MF

'java9' build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.thoughtblaze.java9.main.Main'
ext.moduleName = 'java9main.main'
compileJava {
  inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
  doFirst {
      options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
      ]
      classpath = files()
  }
}
dependencies {
  compile project (':java8')
}
```

'java9' module-info

```
module java9main.main {
  requires java9module.main ;
  requires java8module.main ;
}
```

The problem now is: 
'java9' does not recognize java8 as a required module and therefore I cant access any class of the java8 module.

What do I miss here ?

Comment: What version of Gradle and Java are you using? I gave this a try, and it worked fine for me - https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_java_9/tree/master/egg_35_stack_overflow_48725004

Comment: My Gradle says "4.5"

Comment: Hmmmmm, your code works like a charm... Thanx a lot. Now I can try to figure out where the problem in my code is.

Comment: I only have to find out how to teach IntelliJ that the reference "requires" to the java 8 module shall be found. Currently it regards it as "cannot be found"

Comment: looks like you are declaring a module-info file which depends on the moduleName you are passing to javac with the moduleName parameter; this is not needed, and may be the source of your error (bad error message maybe?).

Comment: also, you should probably list your dependencies first, and/or use afterEvaluate {} to ensure that the references you are listing are fully evaluated before you try to pass them along somewhere else.